# Ubicación de navbar dependiendo de la resolución

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

Es posible tener la barra de navegación en lado izquierdo, pero al hacer la pantalla más pequeña se vaya para la derecha y se alineara con el logo?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="site-header inicio">
  <div class="container h-100 contenedor">
    <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-between">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <a href="/"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="Logotipo"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 nav-top">
        <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row h-100 pb-5 d-flex align-items-end">
      <h1>Venta de Casas & Departamentos Exclusivos de Lujo</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Corrige el post, pero si, se puede en el CSS haciendo uso de media query - [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: No utilices el tamaño de letra grande, parece que estuvieras gritando.

Comment: @Bicho el problema con la letra grande es porque solo pegó el código HTML y por ello se veía así.

Answer (score 1):

Como estás usando flexbox, para cambiar la posición de los enlaces solo usa:

```
.nav-top {order: -1} /* izquierda */
.nav-top {order: 1} /* derecha */
```

Tu verás en que parte de tus media query aplicas el código css.